# Can I assign a literal value for a list of columns in pyspark?

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks

Let's  say I have a list1 = ["a", "b", "c"] and a random dataframe df. I want to add the columns a,b and c to my df, each having a constant value of 1 .Is there any way of doing this for the list of columns, instead of typing .withColumn('a', lit(1)) for each one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `pyspark >= 3.3.0` you can use [`withColumns`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.withColumns.html)

```
df = df.withColumns(dict.fromkeys(list1, F.lit(1)))
```

Alternatively, if you have `pyspark < 3.3.0` then we can use list comprehension to assign the columns

```
df = df.select('*', *[F.lit(1).alias(c) for c in list1])
```